# Prevent log for every copy or move

Tags: yeoman

I'm using Yeoman's `this.fs` API and every file that gets copied or moved gets logged to the console. This clutters the output a lot and gets so long that my (actually quite useful) own logs disappear in the mess.

How can I tell Yeoman *not* to log each and every copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `fs-extra` for all my copy needs instead.